# How to pass a class level generic to a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which accepts a generic parameter

```
class MyClass<D> {

  public void myMethod() {

   }

}
```

Now I have an external API method with the following signature?

```
public static <T> T apiMethod​(String str, java.lang.Class<T> classOfT) {
}
```

I want something like the below, but I'm getting **compilation error**.

```
class MyClass<D> {

      public void myMethod(String str) {
            ApiClass.apiMethod​(str,D); 

       }

 }
```

Any idea of how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. The best you can do is defer the responsibility to the caller, making them pass the class to the constructor.

```
class MyClass<D> {

   private Class<D> clazz;

   MyClass(Class<D> clazz) { 
       this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   public void myMethod() {
       ApiClass.apiMethod​(str, clazz); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome that's what I wanted, many thanks.

Comment: The linked duplicates already contain this answer, so you may aswell delete it again